# How To: Server-Side Filtering with JsGrid

Tags: jsgrid

I'm new to JsGrid. I'm currently loading the data via an Ajax call using the "data" property of the JsGrid config. However, I want to allow the user to filter the data. I understand it can be done client-side or server-side. I don't have a preference but if I go with server-side, it looks like I need the "controller" and implement the "loadData" function. However, the code I've seen sends the "filter" parameter of the "loadData" function to the "data" attribute of the $.ajax() call.

My API is written with Node.js (Express & Body-Parser); what can I expect to receive in my API? Will it be a JSON document with field:value pairs of all the filtered values that were entered in the textboxes by the user? If so, I suppose I need to send those values to my stored procedure (using Tedious)?

I know, sounds obvious, but before I start down that path I want to make sure I'm going in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Here's my prototype code (haven't executed it yet):

```
    var db = {
        loadData: (filter)=>{
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                    url: '/kudosapi/report?member=1',
                    data: filter,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    error: (xhr,status,error)=>{
                        errorHandler(xhr,status,error);
                    },
                    success: (data)=>{
                        // Load grid
                    }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work server-side you’ll need to implement `pageLoading: true` and `pageIndex: n`, and return the data and its length.

Here's an example of how I solved it

```
$("#my-table").jsGrid({
          width: "100%",
          filtering: true,
          inserting: false,
          editing: false,
          sorting: true,
          paging: true,
          pageSize: 4,
          autoload: true,
          pageLoading: true,
          pageIndex: 1,
          controller: {
            loadData: function (filter) {
              var d = $.Deferred();
              var url = "your url";
              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                data: filter
              }).done(function (response) {
                 d.resolve(response);
              });

              return d.promise().then(function(data) {
                var startIndex = (filter.pageIndex - 1) * filter.pageSize;
                return {
                      data: data(startIndex, startIndex + filter.pageSize),
                      itemsCount: data
                };
             });

            }

          },

          fields: []
});
```